# Next JS based site deployed on Vercel does not show background image

Tags: reactjs, deployment, next.js, background, vercel

I built a website on NextJS and deployed it on vercel. On the local environment at `localhost:3000`, it shows the background image but on `vercel`  it does NOT show the background image.

Below are screenshots

**On Vercel :**

[image: local]

**On Local :**

[image: withimg]

I am setting the background image with the tailwindCSS where I defined the images in `tailwind.config.js` file and using them in different components.  But that is not the issue as it is working fine in local envirenment.

I don't know what is the reason that why it is behaving differently.

Project GitHub Link : https://github.com/mohitm15/Weather-Lytics

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using relative imports to the public folder within your tailwind config, you should leverage next's [static file serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) to load images from it.

For example, if you look in the DOM, the URL pathing generated during the build process is trying to utilize `mini-css-extract-plugin` to create a path, but the path is not valid:
[image]

When using static file serving, your tailwind config would change from:

`'day_sun' : "url('../public/back_big.jpg')",`

to:

`'day_sun' : "url('/back_big.jpg')",`

When compiled, the path may look incomplete, but it's actually directing that request to `/public/[image].[ext]`:
[image]

Working demo (the weather searching feature will **not** work since `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY_1` is undefined): https://weather-lytics-refactor.vercel.app/

Comment: Vey Very Thanks Man for solving my query.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I load my images from static file serving, similar bug still happened to my app.

The bug is at my `/public/img` folder. According to the [document](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving), seem like the `/img` folder have similar name with some next file or folder, which can cause bug.

To fix it make sure you don't have any folder name "img" or something like that . . . (name "pic" work for me)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of css background, use JSX styling and the background image will show.

Here is an example.

First import the static image as such.

*import world from "../public/world.png";

Inside the jsx template, use it as background image

- style={{backgroundImage:`url(${world.src})`}}

And don't forget to edit other background properties such as background repeat and background size in the css file.